# 128GB flash drive showing as 4mb

Tags: linux, windows, usb-flash-drive, diskpart

I just found out that the 128GB usb drive that I got 2 days ago doesn't work anymore and instead shows as only a 4mb drive. I tried formatting it, on windows using disk management, diskpart, mini tools disk partitioner but in vain it still only shows as 4 MB disk in all of those tools.

the problem is that the first time when I plugged it, it did register as a 128GB, i did some speed testing, copied some files and then the second time it just didn't work.

is there any way to basically look into its sectors or at least know if it damaged beyond repair or not.

**EDIT :** it does show up only Mac as "uninitialized device"

Comment: Why not return it to the retailer?

Comment: they require the containing box to be fully intact and it had to be torn so that i  can get the flash out so it wasn't accepted.

Comment: I would guess that you were sold a 4mb device which had firmware flashed to look like 128GB, which is pretty much confirmed since you tried to copy files and then couldn't use it again. Definitely try and get it returned or do some sort of chargeback for false advertisement

Comment: Reputable seller would honor their return policy and understand the packaging issue.  Sounds like you were sold a fake device

Comment: Perhaps it just suffered an unusual hardware failure that somehow wasn't picked up by quality control.

Comment: I did open the sub drive and the PCB looked so cheap and nothing like my old usb drives ones with 16Gb and 8GB, it had a winbond chip that I couldn't get the storage capacity of on the internet, data sheets are there but no specific capacity : 
winbond 25q80bvf

Comment: If you are in the EU, then their "they require the containing box to be fully intact" policy is itself fraudulent. You have the right to open the package to use the content. If the package is hard-sealed, that is not your problem. If you bought online & paid by PayPal, take it up with them, they will protect your rights. If you bought it from any reputable online structure, eBay, Amazon etc, tell them too, they will investigate the seller.

Answer (score 2):

Flash drives of 4 MB do not exist, so the firmware of the disk is probably corrupted
and is mis-reporting the disk's size.

You should look on the support website of the manufacturer for a firmware update
utility, which will fix the corrupted firmware by rewriting it.

However, if such a utility does not exist, and as the disk should still be under
guarantee, just send it to be repaired. This will most likely get you a new disk.
This will not work if you trafficked with the disk.

Comment: looking on the internet, I think it is a counterfeit usb drive because it is branded Sony vaio flash drive and Sony doesn't use bio name anymore and never it did for flash drives.

Comment: Possibly. Also the vendor's excuses are not convincing. This might be a lost cause.